# Angular Formly: how do I add a bootstrap input group addon button? Or bootstrap addon dropdown?

Tags: angular-formly

I am a bit new to both Angular.js and Angular-Formly, so please be gentle. I'm trying to create an input that will allow users to enter a value as either a percent, or a dollar amount. So I'd like them to be able to switch or toggle between % and $ with an input group addon button.

Something like this:

[image]

That way they could click on the `$ ⇆ %` button to switch between entering a dollar amount or a percentage.

Another (arguable better option from a UI perspective) would be to have a bootstrap dropdown, but I haven't been able to find an example of how to accomplish that with Formly either.

Something like this:

[image]

In either case, the amount in the input field should show the proper input type (either a $ or %). So if a user switched to percent, the amount would change to something like this:

[image]

**Angular Formly Code:** used to produce the first example above.

```
{
  "className": 'col-sm-6 col-md-4',
  "hideExpression": () => !self.isBehalfType.call(self, LANDLORD),
  "type": 'currency',
  "key": "Search_Yearly_Square_Foot_Rate_Increase__c",
  "templateOptions": {
    "label": 'Projected Rental Increase',
    "maxlength": 8,
    "type": "text",
    "onChange": () => self.updateProforma(),
    "addonLeft": {
      "text":"$ ⇆ %",
    },
    "addonRight": {
      "text": "ft²/yr"
    }
  },
  "ngModelElAttrs": {
    'select-on-click': '',
    "maxlength": "8"
  },
  "defaultValue": self.editedTransaction.Search_Yearly_Square_Foot_Rate_Increase__c || 0
},
```

Any guidance (including any better method that I haven't thought of) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr?That'll help give you a precise answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create a new [formly custom template](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/custom-templates)

Where you setup your angular-formly configuration, likely in an index.config.js file, you'll see the `formlyConfigProvider.setType({})` function used.  That function defines your custom template.

Also, don't think about changing the html via your template instance configuration (the block of "Angular Formly Code" you posted above).  If you need different html, make a new template.